# Python assign an object in a separate module to local variable with using a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my main.py this **works**..... cur_weapon is set to the axe object and I can use it..

```
import weapon

cur_weapon = weapon.axe
print(cur_weapon)
```

i have a class and created the axe object in weapon.py

this will **not**.. ...

```
import weapon

cur_choice = "axe"      
cur_weapon = weapon.cur_choice
print(cur_weapon)
```

AttributeError: module 'weapon' has no attribute 'cur_choice'

do i need to 'dereference' it somehow?  (unsure term)
additionally, any pointers on how to describe this would be great.. (new to python)

```
weapon.py
from random import randint
class Weapon:
    """initalize weapon, defaults to the humble dagger"""
    def __init__(self,
                 name = "humble dagger",
                 two_hand = False,
                 die_dmg = 6,
                 rolls = 1,
                 magic_mod = 0,
                 dmg_type  = "slash",
                 speed = 0,
                 dur = 100,
                 wid = 99):
        
        self.name = name
        self.two_hand = two_hand
        self.die_dmg = die_dmg
        self.rolls = rolls
        self.magic_mod = magic_mod
        self.dmg_type = dmg_type
        self.speed = speed
        self.dur = dur
        self.wid = wid
 
    def attack_dmg(self):
        hit = (randint(1, self.die_dmg) * self.rolls) + self.magic_mod
        print(f"Your {self.name} hits for {hit} damage")
        return hit
        
axe = Weapon("axe", False, 6, 2, 0, "slash", 100, 0, 101)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getattr`

```
cur_weapon = getattr(weapon, cur_choice)
```

This helps to get the attribute when you have a string for the attribute name.